# SQL joining based on CASE result

Tags: sql, join, case

I'm using the following SQL query..

```
    SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN messages.from_user_id = '$user_id' THEN messages.to_user_id
WHEN messages.from_user_id != '$user_id' THEN messages.from_user_id
END as from_user_id
 FROM messages JOIN users ON from_user_id=users.id
```

But then how can I use the `from_user_id` to use in the JOIN statement. It doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 4):

The alias that you are naming in your CASE expression is not available for use in the JOIN.  If you want to use an alias in your JOIN, then you can wrap your CASE in a subquery:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT *,
        CASE
        WHEN messages.from_user_id = '$user_id' THEN messages.to_user_id
        WHEN messages.from_user_id != '$user_id' THEN messages.from_user_id
        END as from_user_id
    FROM messages 
) m
JOIN users 
  ON m.from_user_id=users.id
```